# Android: How to pop up a window by clicking views?

Tags: android, android-menu

Here if that image is clicked, it opens a new window. How to achieve this? Its not a Menu right??

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can set an onClickListener on the ImageView like

```
mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View v) {

                             // start a dialog

                            }
                        });
```

On click, you open a dialog http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html.

Answer (score 0):

`View`'s can trigger the `onClick(View v)` callback if you set the `OnClickListener` upon them. When the callback is invoked, you can simply switch trough View.getId(), in order to understand which `View` has been clicked. If the `view`'s clicked is the right one, instantiate and show your dialog.

Answer (score 0):

try like this.

```
mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        ctContext);
                builder.setItems(listdatatopopulate,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(
                                    DialogInterface dialogInterface,
                                    int item) {
                                // do some thing on item click
                            }
                        });
                builder.create().show();

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `OnCreate` you need `this.registerForContextMenu(mImageView);`
2. use `onClickListener` for `mImageView`:
   `mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
     v.performLongClick();
    }
   });`
3. Implement the context menu http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu